# Office document save as requires further authentication

Tags: sharepoint-server, office, ntlm

- *Professional Plus 2010 14.0.7232.5000*
- *Windows 7 SP1 16.4*
- *SharePoint Server 2013*
- *Site added to local intranet zone*
- *Automatic login enabled*
- *NTLM Claim-based*

---

**Problem**

When editing or even just downloading an office document from SharePoint, the authentication popup appears whilst saving.

[image]

The user has the required permission to save back the document. After logging in, office tries to save back to the origin (SharePoint)

I am aware, that this is the expected behaviour for **editing** a document. But why do I encounter this when **downloading**? I'd expect a local

Why won't office send the current windows user? Is this problem related to any recent patch?

Feel free to ask if further information is required.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you have downloaded the document from search result?

Per my test, there is no download option in the hover panel in the search result, whether you customize the display template in the search result? If so, check if it’s set to get login authentication.

And you can check if the authentication prompt when you download in the document library, and check in another site collection/ web application if the issue exists.